# Angular: Set value of text input without creating a model

Tags: angularjs, forms, angular-ngmodel, angularjs-ng-value

I have a form that lives inside an `ng-repeat`. I'm not using `ng-model` on the form because I don't think there is a need just yet (it's not an AJAX form). I want to set the default value of one of my text input fields to the value of `j.some_attribute`, where `j` is the current iteration of `ng-repeat`. I've tried `value="{{j.some_attribute}}"` and `ng-value="j.some_attribute"`, but neither one works. When the form is submitted, the value for that field is blank. Is there a way to set the default value of a text input without creating a form model on the scope?

Comment: are you getting any console error ?

Comment: Not getting any errors. If I view the page source, I see something like `<input value>` or `<input ng-value>` or `<input value="j.some_attribute>`, depending on if I use value or ng-value and if I enclose the variable in handlebars

Comment: ajax is irrelevant...can use `ng-model` anyway. It will bind to the value property of the element. That being said if `ng-value` not working it sounds like you have a scope issue. Is element inside a directive? Is it a hidden element? Create demo that replicates the problem

Comment: did you forget to put a `name` on element? no `name` means no submit

Comment: It wasn't an issue with `name` not being specified for the inputs, not was it a scope issue. The form was not inside a directive. I couldn't solve the problem the way I'd hoped, so I refactored the form to use ng-model.